# How do I make a blank page if someone directly visits a .php url

Tags: javascript, php

I have form validation setup and working as you can see (using javascript), the only problem is that when someone successfully logs in, I have it redirect to login.php but if someone directly visits mysite.com/login.php they don't need a password to login. If there is any type of php code I need to add then that's fine, another option would be to change the function for the javascript on a successful login. Any info will help!

I have a password only form; here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/account.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Order of Aztec</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" align="center">
<br /><br /><br />
<div align="center"><img src="images/aztec-logo.png" width="256" height="198" alt="Aztec"/></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="error-division"></div>
<br />
<form id="myForm" align="center">
<div align="center"><input placeholder="Password" name="pword" id="pword" type="password" /></div>
<br />
<div align="center" id="agree-box"><input id="agree-box-input" onClick="login();return false;" type="checkbox">Agree that you are part of the steam group "The order of aztec."</input></div>
<br />
<div align="center"><input id="submit" type="submit" /></div>
</form>
<div id="ack"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login()
{
var pass = document.getElementById('pword');

var corpass = "t";

var agree = document.getElementById('agree-box-input');

if(pass.value == corpass && agree.checked == true)
{
window.location = "login.php"
} else {
document.getElementById("error-division").innerHTML = "Wrong password or             agreement not checked. Please try again.";
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(condition) { show something } else { don't }` and use sessions.

Comment: Don't do login verification from client-side. Anyone can just see the password there.

Comment: apart from the addressed, the html `align` attribute is deprecated :)

Comment: This method of validation is only just for fun right? If you want to check whether the user visit login.php directly or not, you could check for the previous Url value (referer Url).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks I didn't know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add if statement in your login.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['your_username']) && isset($_POST['your_password'])){
   // do your activities
}else{ ?>
   <script type="Javascript">
      alert("Your username / password is incorrect");
      window.location = "your_validation_page.php";
   </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JavaScript here. Which is resulting in errors.

Comment: @PocketCraftGaming I've edited my post, it should be working